# splash screen margin problems?

Tags: android, imageview, splash-screen

I am using the following code to display splash screen, but it is showing a margin at the bottom.  Can anyone guide me what mistake am I making here?

My image resolution is  480 x 800.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/splash"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<application android:name="MyApplication" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:configChanges="locale" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

[image]

Comment: while language is english it works perfect and displayed on full screen but when i change language to other than it above image is shown as splash. even in both folder image is same drawable-sr-rRS-hdpi and drawable-en-rUS-port-hdpi image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try to add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your XML ( in your ImageView )

Answer (score 4):

If you want it full screen, try the following.  This should also scale the image to fit the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView 
             android:src="@drawable/splash"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
             android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little addition to the answers already given.If the answers provided do not work for you right away, try removing these (if they exist)

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

That was what I did before William's answer worked for me.